# How to change Colors in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, themes

I recently installed DevStyle in Eclipse and fell in love with the [Light Red Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEOdc.png).

I planned to color my entire Windows with this color scheme. Since Windows 10 doesn't offer a whole lot in terms of Customization, I messed around the Registry in [`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwiFU.png) && [`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfweI.png) with not much success.

The best thing I have managed to change is the Notepad Color, Chrome New Tab Color and some random boxes.

The main goal is to update the update the Explorer from Blinding White to this Mellow Pink.

So I will appreciate it if someone can confirm that it is actually possible through the registry and point me toward the files I need to update.

Answer (score 0):

I can't point you in the direction you need to go, but I can confirm it's possible.   Everything in windows from colours and fonts to how a new activity is launched and kernel management is controlled by the registry. you can change the colours of windows and even change the booting animation in there, but I'm, not 100% sure what you should do so I'm not gonna point you in any direction. ¨

And be careful, you can mess up in the registry, and easily to the point where it's unrecoverable and you need to reinstall windows, Trust me. I'm an IT supporter and I've seen some s***, to say the least